# Character encoding issues in kibana when ingesting data from kafka to elasticsearch

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, kibana

I am ingesting data from kafka into elasticsearch using kafka. 
In Kibana the ingested documents look like the following:
[image]

How can I ensure that the character encoding is correct and ultimately fix this issue?

Comment: What language is it

Comment: it's in english, its mongoDB logs message like: 2020-03-23T22:01:11.836+0100 I -        [conn92350] end connection localhost:port (81 connections now open)

Comment: What is the content of your message?Can you see the contents of `message` correctly in es?

Comment: I found that your source display is of type gz.

Comment: @Johnny the messages are not correct  in es.

Comment: So check your `source` field. @Aymen Rahal